# How to write a spec for class methods that get called on class load?

Tags: ruby, rspec, class-method

```
class A
  include Logging
  log_to 'whatever'
end
```

I want to test if the the method `log_to` gets called with the right parameter. But as you might have guessed, the `log_to` method comes from the Logging module and gets called when the class gets loaded. How do I write a spec or a custom matcher to check if `log_to 'whatever'` is getting called?

Even if I mock the `log_to` method on `class A`, there is no way in the spec to see if it will get called as it gets called during class load. I tried removing the constant and loading it again which does not seem to work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This should probably be in a separate spec file from the spec file that tests the bulk of class A's functionality:

```
describe 'A' do

  it 'should log when loaded' do
    class A ; end
    A.should_receive(:log_to).with('whatever')
    require 'a'
  end

end
```

I would consider, though, changing the class's behavior to something easier to test.  Tests which are unusual in their construction or which have tricky constraints are a code smell, too.

Comment: I agree with you but to make a class log to a different file this way of doing it just makes sense. Doesn't it? If not, can you please suggest a different way?

Comment: @Chirantin, Thinking on it, you're right--the implementation should stand.  I'll try to invent a different way to test it--I'm not too happy with what I've suggested so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should test the desired outcome, not the implementation details. I would test Logging module in isolation like this:

```
describe Logging do
  TEST_IO = StringIO.new

  # some stub class for testing
  class Person
    include Logging
    log_to TEST_IO

    def name
      "Bob"
    end
  end

  after do
    TEST_IO.reopen
  end

  it "logs a method call to the given io" do
    person = Person.new
    TEST_IO.string.should eq("")
    person.name
    TEST_IO.string.should eq("name called\n")
  end

  # ...
end
```

And I am not sure I would test the real class that uses this module at all since it is very simple and does contain any dangerous logic. Accidental mistakes like syntactic errors will be caught by an integration test.